# Java: Issue with jsplitpane and boxlayout

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane, boxlayout

I want to get rid of the empty space to the left of the jsplitpanes:

[image: screenshot]

Here's my code:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
splitPane.add(downloadsPanel);
splitPane.add(filesPanel);

JSplitPane splitPane2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
splitPane2.add(processingPanel);
splitPane2.add(messagePanel);

JSplitPane splitPane3 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);

splitPane3.add(splitPane);
splitPane3.add(splitPane2);

getContentPane().add(addPanel);
getContentPane().add(splitPane3);
```

Comment: That "empty space" is your addPanel. So what the heck is this addPanel?

Comment: Why would the JSplitPanes not automatically stretch to the width of the parent Frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BoxLayout does weird things with the alignment of components. Read the section from the swing tutorial on [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment). In short, make sure the alignment of the addPanel and splitPane3 are the same:

```
component.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

It looks to me like one defaults to CENTER and the other defaults to LEFT.